Is It Legal in the United States for a Merchant to Refuse Legal Tender?
This question is motivated by the following comment:

"And yes, I asked to pay in cash and was refused."

found here: Is this misleading "convenience fee" legal?
Cash is legal tender.
QUESTION: Can a merchant in the United States refuse to be paid in legal tender?
